# Authorizing to Spotify API from Perl

Tags: perl, oauth-2.0, spotify

I'd like to ask for clue how to fill-in correctly parameters, to get an access token to Spotify API. Using the LWP::Authen::OAuth2 module initialized following the guidelines at [Spotify authorization guide](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow)

```
use LWP::Authen::OAuth2;
my $oauth2 = LWP::Authen::OAuth2->new(
    client_id => '...',
    client_secret => '...',
    #authorization_endpoint => 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    #token_endpoint => 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
);
$oauth2->post(
    'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    grant_type => 'client_credentials'
);
```

The post method however gives an error:
"request" on an undefined value at D:\Perl\site\lib/LWP/Authen/OAuth2.pm line 104."

Furthermore, once I obtain the access token, can I feed it to standard LWP::UserAgent object or am I obligated to continue requests using the $oauth2 object? Thanks.